# How to remove elements from an array in Jsonb. Using Postgres

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, function

I used the `( fields -> ?1 ) - string_to_array( ?2, ',' )` function. To remove the elements that are in the array, however, the function adds to jsonb those that do not contain in the first array. I would only like to remove those that are in the second array, and not also add those that do not contain

Added the elements that were not equal

This is my function:

```
( fields -> ?1 ) - string_to_array( ?2, ',' )
```

my jsonb field is something like:

```
{
"23": [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ]
}
```

with what I did if I passed the function with this second array:

```
 [ "aaa", "jjj", "ddd" ]
```

Returning:

```
{
"23": [ "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "jjj ]
}
```

Expected:

```
 {
    "23": [ "bbb", "ccc" ]
 }
```

my expected return is just remove:

```
`aaa`
```

remove the same fields and not add the different ones

```
update mytable
set fields = 
    jsonb_set(fields, '{23}', (fields->'23') - [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ] );
```

Comment: Can you update your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: @SelVazi•  
I updated the question, can you tell me if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) as follows :

To remove one single element from the array :

```
update mytable
set fields = 
    jsonb_set(fields, '{23}', (fields->'23') - 'aaa');
```

This is to remove an array from an other array :

```
update mytable
set fields = 
    jsonb_set(fields, '{23}', (fields->'23') - '{"aaa", "jjj", "ddd"}'::text[]);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nqW3GDJ8)

Comment: but in this case if the second array has elements that are not in the first, those elements are added to the first one as well. remove the same and add the different

Comment: Your question is to remove elements of array from an other array, if those elements not exists they will not be removed right ?